# Load jQuery in content-script only when a preference is set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension.

I'd like to load jQuery in my content script. 
That's pretty easy if I ship `jquery.js` and change the manifest

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    { "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"], ...    }
   ],
...
}
```

Now, I need jQuery only if the user has checked the corresponding option in the option page.

In order to optimize my code, how can I load jQuery in my content script only when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. There is an example on the content_script [documentation page](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi).